# Layout Update for All actions of a controller

Tags: magento-1.7, layout

I want to write a common update handle for managing few layout updates that apply to all actions of same controller

e.g. I have `<checkout_onestep_index>` `<checkout_onestep_review>`, `<checkout_onestep_shipping>`, etc. is it possible that I can write layout changes for all actions in one single handle like `<checkout_onestep_default>` OR `<checkout_onestep_all>`
Here are my common changes for all actions of `onestep` controller.

```
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>mage/translate.js</name></action>            
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>quicklogin/tinybox.js</name></action>           
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>customerlocator/styles.css</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>mage/directpost.js</name></action>
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>mage/centinel.js</name></action>

        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/new.checkout.css</name></action>

    </reference>

    <remove name="left"/>
    <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>


    <reference name="header">
        <action method="unsetChildren"></action>
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/header.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_headbar" template="checkout/cart/header.phtml" />
    </reference>

    <reference name="footer">
        <action method="unsetChildren"></action>
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/footer.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

Thanks for your help !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a layout handle like you said `<checkout_onestep_default>` with your directives but then you have to add in the specific layouts for each action this:

```
<update handle="checkout_onestep_default" />
```

The markup above will merge the handle of a specific action with your handle.

Comment: its exactly what I was looking for. I knew it and I forgot. Thanks for saving the day bro.